# how to set breadcrumbs?

Tags: python, django, breadcrumbs

please tell me how to use breadcrumbs in django1.6/python3.3.

I installed the [module here](https://github.com/chronossc/django-breadcrumbs/). then added, 'breadcrumbs' in INSTALLED_APPS.

then added, 'breadcrumbs.middleware.BreadcrumbsMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

then added, 'django.core.context_processors.tz', 'django.core.context_processors.request' in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

then added in views.py:

```
def inner_page (request, slug = 'index'):
request.breadcrumbs ("qwerty", request.path_info)

t = loader.get_template ('inner_page.html')
c = None

if slug == 'index':
content = Page.get_main_pages (request)
c = RequestContext (request, {
'title': 'Main page',
'content': content,
'slug': 'index',
}, [Custom_proc])
else:
content = Page.get_page (slug)
c = RequestContext (request, {
'title': slug,
'content': content,
'slug': slug,
}, [Custom_proc])

try:
c! = None
except NameError:
raise Http404
else:
return HttpResponse (t.render (c))
```

then added to base.html:

```
<div>
{% For breadcrumb in request.breadcrumbs%}
<a href="{{ breadcrumb.url }}"> {{breadcrumb.name}} </ a> {% if not forloop.last%} » {% Endif%}
{% Endfor%}
<div>
```

as a result of the console displays the following error [message](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/err.png)

Comment: From your error, clearly the breadcrumbs import is not working, and you are using Python 3, which I'm not sure the project supports. Can you try the same code with Python 2.7? Or, ask the developer via an issue on the Github repository.

Comment: Also, just some friendly advice, you should format your code in your post...you will generally get a better response here on SO :)